# Is it possible to retrieve a task result and pass it as a parameter to a deployed ssis package?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Is it possible to retrieve a task result and pass it as a parameter to a deployed ssis package?

I'm trying to set up a scheduled ssis package task that I can pass new parameters to. Is there a better way to do this?

thanks in advance

Comment: It depends. I think you need to explain your question in detail. In some scenarios it is possible. For example this can be done with a Configuration file or by software like ActiveBatch.

Comment: What do you mean by task? Do you mean a task in a SSIS package (Execute SQL, Data Flow, Execute Process?) or a windows scheduled task or a SQL Agent job task or some other kind of task? You can certainly pass parameters into packages but the method depends on the version - please update your question with all this info and we can help. Can you also explain what you are trying to achieve. We can't comment on whether there is a 'better way to do this' without knowing what you are trying to achieve and without knowing your criteria for 'better'

Comment: I was meaning a SQL Agent Task. I would be open to other solutions. If I can have a ssis package run by it's self and have it be fed with new parameters every time it runs I would be more than thrilled. I have a ssis package that runs perfectly but i have to update its project parameters (I can switch it to package parameters) I can get the results  I want with a result of SQL Agent job task. I am having some trouble finding how to connect the two. Thank you for your responses. I'll look into a Config file and ActiveBatch.

Comment: Hey I found out how to solve my problem by putting my task's logic into a "execute sql task" then had  results it into the result set as the parameters in my package. From there I can deploy my package as usual. thank you for your responses.